# Is it true that $P(A)\leq P(A\cap B\cap C)+P(B^c)+P(C^c)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality, self-learning

I am reading a paper, and there is an inequality which is printed below.

[image]

It seems he uses a result similar to $P(A)\leq P(A\cap B\cap C)+P(B^c)+P(C^c)$ for measurable sets $A,B,C$. I can't conclude if this inequality holds in general.

Is it true? Can you show it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if something is in $A$, then it's either in $B$ and $C$ or not. If it's not [in $B$ and $C$], then it's either in $B^c$ or $C^c$.

Comment: I agree with you. How would you show this?

Comment: "this"=your argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
A&=A\cap\left((B\cap C)\cup\left(B\cap C\right)^c\right)\\
 &=(A\cap B\cap C) \cup \left(A\cap \left(B^c\cup C^c\right)\right)\\
&\subseteq (A\cap B\cap C) \cup \left(B^c\cup C^c\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! If one uses the monotonicity of the measure, then we are done!